# AdventureWorks 2014 database for SQLite

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

For university purpose I need to use `AdventureWorks` 2014 sample database. What I can download is a `.bak` file to use with SQL Server, but I'm using DataGrip with SQLite on MacBook. How can I convert it or get it to work with my setup?

Comment: You can *also* download the AdventureWorks **install scripts** (SQL scripts) from here: https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks - but of course, that is SQL Server / T-SQL code - not the SQLite dialect.

Answer (score 1):

If you are required to use the AdventureWorks database for your course, you will need access to an instance of SQL Server. There is no way around this. You can install Developer or Express edition in a Windows VM on your MacBook, dual-boot Windows via Boot Camp, get access to a server on-campus, or set up a VM on Azure or AWS with SQL Server on it and restore the database there.

There is no way to use a SQL Server database backup file with SQLite or any other RDBMS that isn't SQL Server. Further, I expect that if your course requires this database for the assignments, "converting" it to SQLite isn't going to do you any good because of the differences between the two RDBMSs - they use different dialects of SQL and have different features.